# Pass results of LINQ through FOREACH and display on label

Tags: asp.net, foreach, label

```
    ChecklistRecordEntry =
            (from CRE in db.Checklist_Record_Entries
             where CRE.Check_List_Records_Id == checklistRecordId
             select CRE).ToList();

        foreach (Checklist_Record_Entry CRE in ChecklistRecordEntry)
        {
            comment.Text = CRE.Comment;
        }
```

At the 2 records are stored in 'ChecklistRecordEntry' I want to loop through them and bind it to the label 'comment' but then each time the loop goes around it rewrites over the previous one

```
<asp:Label ID="comment" runat="server" />
```

What can I do so every time it goes round the loop it adds a new label underneath the previous one (which will be displayed on screen)- instead of using the same label...thanks

---

Thanks for the reply everyone..all good help...bit of a problem trying to display each record inside a seperate row on a table though

```
<table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:200px;"></th>    
                    <th style="width:200px;">Item</th>    
                    <th style="width:200px;"></th>    
                    <th style="width:200px;"></th>    
                    <th style="width:200px;"><asp:Label ID="CommentHeader" Text="Comment" /></th>    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style="width:200px;"><asp:Label ID="Comment" runat="server"/></th>  
                </tr>
</table>
```

Displays the results all inside one cell...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a repeater, it is pretty much straightforward:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptComments" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:200px;"></th>    
                <th style="width:200px;">Item</th>    
                <th style="width:200px;"></th>    
                <th style="width:200px;"></th>    
                <th style="width:200px;"><asp:Label ID="CommentHeader" Text="Comment" /></th>    
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Comment") %></th>  
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then bind the data to the repeater:

```
ChecklistRecordEntry =
        (from CRE in db.Checklist_Record_Entries
         where CRE.Check_List_Records_Id == checklistRecordId
         select CRE).ToList();

rptComments.DataSource = ChecklistRecordEntry;
rptComments.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would i bind it inside my for loop as    foreach (Checklist_Record_Entry CRE in ChecklistRecordEntry)
        {
            rptComments.DataBind = string.Join("<br />",
            ChecklistRecordEntry.Select(a => a.Comment));
        }

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use some temp string variable in code-behind, which will be updated by += in foreach, and then, after foreach is done assingn to comment.Text this temp variable

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this:

```
foreach (Checklist_Record_Entry CRE in ChecklistRecordEntry)
{
    comment.Text += CRE.Comment + "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine but I would suggest using `String.Join`.

```
comment.Text = string.Join("<br />", 
    ChecklistRecordEntry.Select(a => a.Comment));
```

You also don't need to use `ToList()` for this, since this will accept an `IEnumerable`.